# C# Forms: Raise mouse event (pass from child to parent)

Tags: c#, event-handling, mousedown

Looking for any solution.
I have a user control with several textboxes. When placed on a form, MouseDown and MouseMove events are only triggered if clicked on user control body, but not when clicked in text box.
Is it possible to raise user control's mousedown event when textbox mousedown event happens?
Or is it possible to pass events from object to its parent? (and still be able to click the textbox to edit it?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I have handled the TextBoxes `MouseDown` event. From here, you can raise the `MouseDown` event of the UserControl that holds your `TextBox`.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseDown(e); // Goes through as a MouseDown Event from UserControl1
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirements, this may not work for you as when the `MouseDown` of the UserControl is handled, it will come through as being originated by `UserControl` (The sender parameter will refer to UserControl1.

I also extracted the `OnMouseDown` implementation of the `Control` class to see if it could be used:

```
        // Extracted using Reflection
        // This will not compile as Control.EventMouseDown is a private member
        System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler mouseEventHandler = (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler)this.Events[System.Windows.Forms.Control.EventMouseDown];
        if (mouseEventHandler == null)
            return;
        mouseEventHandler(sender, e);
```

Unfortunately, the events are stored in a Private member and not readily accessible.

If you want to know and handle the `MouseDown` event differently if it originates from a TextBox, you will have to declare and raise a custom event.

**Declare Custom Event**

```
public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> TextBoxMouseDownEvent;
```

**Raise Custom Event from TextBox_MouseDown**

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> handler = TextBoxMouseDownEvent;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first snippet solved my problem.
I'm used to vb .net, and am forcing my self to write everything in c#, so sometimes i get stuck on trivial problems.
Thanks!

Comment: @TomislavPlečko You can use this website to convert C# to VB.Net code
[https://converter.telerik.com][1]